# Hide / Replace broken image in PHP for a users website post

Tags: php, html

On our website, we have a classifieds section.

If a user does not add an image in their Classifieds listing in the Classifieds section, how can I hide the broken image icon and show my own default image instead.

See issue on my [website](http://thediamondscondos.com/residents.html)

Let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I hide broken images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545132/can-i-hide-broken-images)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [Inputting a default image in case the src attribute of an html <img> is not valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/980910/784648) which provides some HTML only solutions to this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235913/how-to-silently-hide-image-not-found-icon-when-src-source-image-is-not-found

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a validation on your code to check if the image is missing on your condition create a default image if there is no image uploaded.

```
if(!empty($image['imageuploaded'])){
   /** display the uploaded image 
}else{
 /** Display default
}
```